# GridView dynamically loading shows previous data

Tags: qt, gridview, qml, swipeview

I have swipeView with GridView. I am creating Gridview dynamically based on my model count. (Each gridView holds maximun 6 cell only.
 ie, if the model count is 7 I am creating second gridView with the last Item). It is working fine.

**I am facing an issue:**
If I have two gridViews, while scroll to the second item, the second view shows the same first view contents up to the data loaded to the second GridView.
Here is my code, is there any issues in my code ? or How can I fix the issue.

```
SwipeView {
                id: home_Swipe
                width: 1280 
                height: 542 
                x:145 
                y:0 
    // favouriteapp  is model Id
                Repeater{
                    model:Math.ceil(favouriteapp.count /6)
                    Component {

                        id: contactDelegate
                        QuadTiles{
                            id: gridItem
                            btn1_icon.source:favouriteapp.get(nIndex).icon1
                            btn3_icon.source:favouriteapp.get(nIndex).icon2

                            Connections{
                                target:gridItem
                                // Selected 1st button from the grid
                                onGridButton1Pressed:{
                                favouriteapp.setProperty(selectedItemIndex,"isLoaded",true)

                                }
                            }


                        } 

                    }//Component

                    GridView{
                        id: grid
                        x: 0
                        y: 20
                        width: 1280
                        height: 542
                        interactive: false

                        cellWidth: 360
                        cellHeight:240

                        model: utilObj.getPageGridCount(favouriteapp.count,home_Swipe.currentIndex)
                        delegate:contactDelegate

                    }


                } // Repeater



            }// SwipeView
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I think, is, that `Math.ceil(count / 6)` is the same for up to 6 values. When the value does not change, it won't trigger an update.
Try to add as much elements, so the value would rise by 1.
I am sure, then it will update.

A short and dirty workaround would be to go procedural, first setting the `Repeater`'s model to 0 and then back to the original value every time.
I don't have QT installed on my current device, but I am 100% sure, this would work.

To do this, you need to handle the signal in the `favoriteapp.onCountChanged`-handler setting the model first to 0, and after that back to `Math.ceil(count/6)`